# Thymeleaf: How to read variables from page context in the processor class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf, pagecontext

In my current spring-boot project I have a view mapped in my controller this way:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "cadastra")
  @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_'+#this.this.name)")
  @Menu(label = "cadastra")
  public String cadastra(Model model) throws Exception {
    model.addAttribute("command", serv.newObject());
    return "private/cadastra";
  }
```

the html page have a structure like that:

```
  <form:form action="cadastra">
    <field-box th:each="item : ${command.getClass().getDeclaredFields()}">
      <div th:each="item2 : ${item.getDeclaredAnnotations()}">
        <div th:switch="${item2.annotationType().getSimpleName()}">
          <div th:case="'Checkbox'"><field:checkbox/></div>
          <div th:case="'DataList'"><field:datalist/></div>
          <div th:case="'Input'"><field:input/></div>
          <div th:case="'Radiobutton'"><field:radio/></div>
          <div th:case="'Select'"><field:select/></div>
          <div th:case="'Textarea'"><field:textarea/></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </field-box>
  </form:form>
```

the code for the processor for the tag `form:form` is that:

```
public class Form extends AbstractProcessor {
  public static Element form = new Element("form");

  private String action;

  private String object;

  @Override
  public ProcessorResult doProcess(Arguments arguments,ProcessorMatchingContext context,Node node) {
    Element parent = (Element) node;
    setAction( parent.getAttributeValue("action") );

    form.setProcessable(true);
    form.setAttribute("role", "form");
    form.setAttribute("class", "form");
    form.setAttribute("action", "");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    node.getParent().insertBefore(node, form);

    List<Element> lista = node.getParent().getElementChildren();
    for(Element child : lista) {
      if(!child.getOriginalName().equals("form")) child.moveAllChildren(form);
    }

    List<Element> lista2 = form.getElementChildren();
    for(Element child : lista2) {
      child.setProcessable(true);
    }

    node.getParent().removeChild(node);
    return ProcessorResult.OK;
  }

  @Override
  public int getPrecedence() {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public IProcessorMatcher<? extends Node> getMatcher() {
    return new ElementNameProcessorMatcher("form");
  }

  public String getAction() {
    return action;
  }

  public void setAction(String action) {
    this.action = action;
  }

  public String getObject() {
    return object;
  }

  public void setObject(String object) {
    this.object = object;
  }
}
```

Right now, I am looking for a way to read in this class FormProcessor the variable `command` from page context, to be able to store the value `command.getClass().getSimpleName()` to the attribute `object`.

Anyone can tell if this is possible and how to accomplish that?

Comment: Are you trying to generate the form dynamically based on the command object? I just created similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30093414/2944265), but I'd like more, if the form:form tag will render itself completely. Is it possible to generate the HTML inside the processor code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to solve this with this code:

```
Map<String, Object> map = arguments.getContext().getVariables();
setObject( map.get("command") );
```

where object is a attribute from the processor class.