# Thymeleaf automatic form generation

Tags: html, forms, thymeleaf

I'd like to create form in specific way. The form should be able to render itself based on received data, should be used like that:

```
 <form action="#" th:action="@{/blahblah}" th:formDefinition="${formDef}" th:object="${formData}"method="post">
```

This should render the necessary input elements in some way, fill in the data etc. Is there a way how to achieve this in Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nope there is no such** way in pure `thymeleaf` which you can do this.

But you have an option to do something like this using **fragments**.

1. Create a `th:fragment` which takes the parameters `formDef` and `formData`
2. In the fragment, create a loop and geenrate the form as you want `dynamically`
3. Call the fragment using `th:include` with the real parameters in the places where you need the form to get generated.

Comment: Can I at least create some "dialect" and pack it with the fragment together? If I'm about to use it in different projects and I don't like the idea of copy/paste the fragment code.

Comment: That's a good idea. If you like to work on an opensource project in that aspect, feel free to contact me as well. I can also provide you my hand on contributing to the project as such. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache Freemaker to create templates in Netbeans IDE. Using this templates, auto-generate your forms from your Entities. This allows you to apply the principle of DRY.....Dont Repeat Yourself in your SDLC.

For more infor, watch the below clip on how they have applied the principle:

https://nofluffjuststuff.com/blog/reza_rahman/2015/01/vaadin_cdi_and_java_ee